# IBM MobileFirst 8.0 Console - com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

In IBM MobileFirst 8.0 Console, when selecting Application push tab.

Following error is occurred sometimes and that particular tab is getting stuck though it is configured and working fine.

**Error is:**
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 8 path $

Please check the attached image for Error:

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b8ni.png)

Now Am solving this issue by stopping mfpserver and restarting, so it is working fine as it is not stuck and error is solved.

Please check the attached image for solved console push tab stuck error:

[Solved issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTMBv.png)

How can i solve this issue without restarting mfpserver?

Comment: Most common cause of the issue is a mis configuration of JNDI properties in either or both admin and push definitions. 
Verify your imfpush JNDI definitions ( specifically the urls) to see if they are proper and accessible all the time.
When opening the PMR make sure you add the server.xml

Answer (score 0):

Not a question for Stack Overflow.
Please open a PMR (support ticket) for IBM and provide to the support team the server logs for the time when this error happens.

You can find the server log file at: [devkit installation directory]/mfp-server/usr/servers/mfp/logs -> messages.log.